# Cloudfront Signed Cookie does not work as expected

Tags: iframe, cookies, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I got an 'access denied' error when I tried to use [Signed Cookie](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html) to access content via Cloudfront

[image]

I think the signature, policy and key pair id are correct because if I construct a signed url with the same values, it works.

My questions:

1. What is the best way to debug this issue? If I turn on logging in cloudfront, will the log helps me to find out the issue?

Assuming my server is `local.example.com` and the cloudfront server CNAME is `test.example.com`,

2. Because ultimately the content will be displayed in an iframe, I set the cookie domain to `.example.com` (note the leading dot). Is it going to cause the 'AccessDenied' issue? As you can see from the above screen shot the cookies are set.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and just found your question. Have you had any luck? With my issue, it appears that whilst the cookies are being set, they're not being sent to cloudfront.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this too.  I notice in your screenshot that you're sending a "CloudFront-Policy" cookie.  I didn't see mention of that in the docs.  There was a "CloudFront-Expires" cookie referenced there that I don't see in your screenshot.

[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-canned-policy.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-canned-policy.html)

Have you by chance been able to figure it out?

Comment: Hello @AnthonyKong, I am running into the same problem and was wondering if you ever solved this problem, if yes please post an answer. Thank you!!